# Error intentun Savechanges() Entity Framework 6 ASP.Net MVC5?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

Cuando actualizo mi objecto gender, me trae la fecha de creation con los siguientes datos, la cual no debería porque tiene un valor asignado en la base de datos, me sale la siguiente fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que me muestra cuando intento hacer el `savechanges()` es el siguiente

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Revisa este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284996/4092887).

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave esta solucion se que si funciona si coloco el campo fecha a que acepte valores null pero no quiero eso quiero saber porque  no me trae la fecha que tengo en la base de datos con ese registro

Comment: Considero que debe [edit] su respuesta para agregar mas detalles como: ¿dónde está llamando a la función "Update"?, tal vez *(y sin haber visto el código)* está instanciando mal las fechas o la entidad `Gender`... Para que la comunidad entienda mejor tu pregunta, debes lees [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Luego [edit] la pregunta.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave creo que si las estuviera instanciando mal no pudiera agregar un registro lo cual puedo, el inconveniente es cuando busco los datos de ese objecto para luego actualizarlos

Comment: El incoveniente puede ser por los formatos de fecha si tu codigo tiene formato mm/dd/yy y tu base de datos dd/mm/yy al tratar de entrar las fechas es muy posible que ocurra un desbordamiento es decir que este fuera de rango, revisa esta posibilidad..

Comment: el problema no es ese ya lo probé es cuando busco el objecto que no me trae los datos de la fecha de creacion de ese registro me lo pone en 1/1/0001 12:00 AM ese es el inconveniente

Answer (score 1):

Creo que este approach podría funcionar, si la columna CreationDate en tu DB es de tipo DATETIME.

```
public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);
```

[Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: sería ideal que replantees tu aporte, pues esta observación ya esta dada a conocer en su propia pregunta, entonces aquí lo necesario es **mostrar como resolverlo**

Comment: además si el enlace provee la respuesta, es deber tuyo añadir el contenido aquí y dejar el enlace como referencia; caso específico si vas a usar la respuesta de alguien mas, es necesario referenciar al autor original

Comment: @shadow una dudam solo deberia de porner el enlace, porque la otra respuesta esta en inglés y es extensa?

Comment: tradúcela es perfectamente válido, al final deja el enlace a dicha respuesta para darle créditos al autor original