# Error al intentar un update con entity framework ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, entity-framework-6

tengo el siguiente inconveniente cuando intento actualizar el objecto Gender, me muestra el siguiente error cuando hago el update, ayuda

```
    try
    {
        Common.Entities.Gender gender = this.genderRepository.FindGenderId(genderModel.GenderId);

        Domain.Models.Gender myGender = new Domain.Models.Gender
        {
            GenderId = gender.GenderId,
            GenderName = genderModel.GenderName,
            CreateBy = gender.CreateBy,
            CreationDate = gender.CreationDate,
            ModifiedBy = genderModel.ModifiedBy,
            ModifiedDate = genderModel.ModifiedDate,
        };

        this.genderRepository.UpdateGender(myGender);
        serviceResult.Data = "Genero modificado.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        serviceResult.Data = "Ocurrio un error modificado el genero.";
        serviceResult.RegisterError(ex);
    }

    return serviceResult;
}
```

y este el el objecto que creo para que me actualize los datos para hacer el update

```
public void UpdateGender(Models.Gender myGender)
{

    this.unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Gender>().Update(new Gender
    {
        GenderId = myGender.GenderId,
        GenderName = myGender.GenderName,
        CreateBy = myGender.CreateBy,
        CreationDate = myGender.CreationDate,
        ModifiedBy = myGender.ModifiedBy,
        ModifiedDate = myGender.ModifiedDate,
    });

    this.unitOfWorkModel.Commit();
    this.unitOfWorkModel.Dispose();
}
```

Esta es la imagen, con el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El codigo debe ir como texto. Mas alla de eso, dice que estas violando la PK. no hay mucho que podamos hacer salvo que des mas informacion.

Comment: @gbianchi listo edite la pregunta

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera, en esta linea: `this.genderRepository.UpdateGender(myGender);` ¿es necesario hacer esa instancia?, ¿y si prueba pasándole directamente la variable `gender`?. Por cierto, ¿esta pregunta está relacionada a esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226480/78)?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave si es neesario para que me llame al metodo que se encuentra en el repositorio y me llegue el objecto con los datos y actualizarlo

Answer (score 0):

Una de las soluciones es que realices el `Select` *(Metodo para seleccionar los registros)* antes de la actualización. Lo que lograras es que se almacene en caché el registro cuando se encuentre. Debes agregar `AsNoTracking()` en el método de que estés utilizando para seleccionar los datos.

Comment: intente utilizar el select para proyectar los datos y no me funciono, pero no probe el metodo que indicaste, pero me seguia lanzando el mismo error